# Converting pandas DataFrame to numpy array but with an inconsistency

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-structures, data-science

I am running into a weird inconsistency. So I had to learn the difference between immutable and mutable data types. For my purpose, I need to convert my pandas DataFrame into Numpy apply operations and convert it back, as I do not wish to alter my input.

so I am converting like follows:

```
mix=pd.DataFrame(array,columns=columns)
def mix_to_pmix(mix,p_tank):
    previous=0
    columns,mix_in=np.array(mix) #<---
    mix_in*=p_tank
    previous=0
    for count,val in enumerate(mix_in):
        mix_in[count]=val+previous
        previous+=val

    return pd.DataFrame(mix_in,columns=columns)
```

This works perfectly fine, but the function:

```
columns,mix_in=np.array(mix)
```

seems to not be consistent as in the case:

```
def to_molfrac(mix):
    columns,mix_in=np.array(mix)
    shape=mix_in.shape

    for i in range(shape[0]):
        mix_in[i,:]*=1/max(mix_in[i,:])
    for k in range(shape[1]-1,0,-1):
        mix_in[:,k]+=-mix_in[:,k-1]
    mix_in=mix_in/mix_in.sum(axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
    return pd.DataFrame(mix_in,columns=columns)
```

I receive the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

The input of the latter function is the output of the previous function. So it should be the same case.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to understand the input of `to_molfrac` and `mix_to_pmix` without an example.
But the pandas objects has a `.value` attribute which allows you to access the underlying numpy array. So, its probably better to use `mix_in = mix.values` instead.

```
columns, values = df.columns, df.values
```